# Complicating Something Simple

Tags: word-request

Is there a word to describe the act of making something unnecessarily complex in order to intentionally or unintentionally disguise one's own ignorance?

Comment: [befuddle, bewilder, disorient, distract, mislead, baffle..](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/befuddle)

Comment: [Obfuscate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate).

Comment: While obfuscate is a really good word for "complicating something simple", it doesn't have the connotation that you're doing it to hide your ignorance. It's commonly used to mean hiding the truth or as a [programming term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) for altering your source code to make it hard to understand.

Comment: I might use [convolute](https://www.wordnik.com/words/convolute) -  practice sophistry; change the meaning of or be vague about in order to mislead or deceive. For example "Her story was so convoluted that I couldn't decide if she was a liar or just [scatterbrained](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scatterbrained)."

Comment: Note [overcomplicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overcomplicate).  Though it doesn't carry the sinister overtones, it is a single word.

Answer (score 1):

> "Creative misunderstandings":

"Breeding confusion on a subject. Providing facts that will sway someone to believe something that they shouldnt. Manipulation, etc. Complicating something that is simple. Creating a misunderstanding to support your own interests."

From: https://quizlet.com/14624488/us-history-1-flash-cards/

Also, obfuscate, as suggested by stangdon.

See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate

Comment: I've never heard or used "creative misunderstandings". I searched and found it in a lot of academic papers and text books, but it seems like a phrase that has a somewhat limited audience.

Comment: Yes, and a pity, too. It's so much more colorful and accessible than "obfuscate."

Comment: I agree - I always have trouble spelling and pronouncing obfuscate. For some reason I want it to be obs-fucate.

Comment: Me too! :-) I Googled, Is there a word for "complicating something that is simple"? and found "creative misunderstandings" amongst the responses, on "flash cards" no less  (presumably for students).

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscate comes closest, and it does have a connotation of intention to cloud the issue. However, intentional disguise of ignorance would require a phrase, as it is not, to my knowledge, available as a single word. Other words to investigate, for similar meanings, would include pettifoggery, shuckster, huckster, and shyster. And don't forget the old standby, bullshit.